# logy axis using plotly.graph_objects

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-dash, scatter-plot

I'm trying to draw a curve using plotly.graph_objects on a figure that already has a scatter plot that is animated. Everything is fine, except that I can't make the y axis logarithmic.

This is one approach:

```
# Creating DataFrames with columns 'enthalpy1', 'pressure' for the trace data
        df_enthalpy1 = pd.DataFrame({'enthalpy1': enthalpy1, 'pressure': pressure})
        df_enthalpy2 = pd.DataFrame({'enthalpy2': enthalpy2, 'pressure': pressure})

        # Using Plotly Graph Objects to create line plots with linear style
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=df_enthalpy1['enthalpy1'], y=df_enthalpy1['pressure'], mode='lines',
                       line=dict(color='blue', dash='solid', width=2), name='Saturated liquid'))
        fig.update_yaxes(type="log")

        # Set the y-axis type to "log" for logP-h diagram
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=df_enthalpy2['enthalpy2'], y=df_enthalpy2['pressure'], mode='lines',
                       line=dict(color='red', dash='solid', width=2), name='Saturated Vapor'))
        fig.update_yaxes(type="log")
```

This is another approach:

```
# Using Plotly Express to create line plots with linear style
    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(df_enthalpy1, x='enthalpy1', y='pressure', line_shape='linear', line_dash='solid',
                color_discrete_sequence=['blue'], name='Saturated liquid'))
    
    # Set the y-axis type to "log" for logP-h diagram
    fig.update_yaxes(type="log")
    
    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(df_enthalpy2, x='enthalpy2', y='pressure', line_shape='linear', line_dash='solid',
                color_discrete_sequence=['red'], name='Saturated Vapor'))
```

I also tried plotly.express scatter, log_x works but not log_y.

I would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean that it's not working. Seems to work for me:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = x**2
fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=x, y=y)])
fig.show()
```

[image]

```py
fig.update_yaxes(type='log')
fig.show()
```

[image]